# How to merge seperates minify-js files into one file in github actions?

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, github-actions, pipeline

I have 4 different minify-js files.

My directory is like this:

```
- src
  - live
   .global-minify.js
   .script-minify.js

  - min
   .minify.min.js
   .script-1.min.js
   .script-2.min.js
   .script-3.min.js
```

I need to add another step into my YAML file to merge them into one and push the live folder.

For example:

- After the run pipeline, the ***minify.min.js*** file should be renamed as ***global-minify.js*** and committed into the live folder.
- After the run pipeline, ***script-1.min.js***, ***script-2.min.js*** and ***script-3.min.js*** files should merge into one file with a new name which is the script-minify.js file, and then committed to live folder again.

Basically, ***the global-minify.js*** file should include just the ***minify.min.js*** file.

The ***script-minify.js*** file should include the other rest of the files which is ***script-1.min.js, script-2.min.js, script-3.min.js***

How can I merge them into one file? and rename them?

This is my YAML file:

```
name: Upload to S3

on:
push:
branches:
  - test-s3
paths:
  - "f/js/bc-global.js"
  - "f/js/scripts/**.js"

jobs:
 deploy:
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@master
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Auto Minify for global.js
    uses: nizarmah/auto-minify@v2.1
    with:
      directory: "f/js/bc-global.js"
      output: "f/src/min/"
      js_engine: uglify-js

  - name: Auto Minify for script folder
    uses: nizarmah/auto-minify@v2.1
    with:
      directory: "f/src/scripts/**.js"
      output: "f/src/min/"
      js_engine: uglify-js

  - name: Auto committing minified files
    uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
    with:
      repository: "f/src/min/"
      commit_message: "Github Action: Auto Minified JS files"
      branch: ${{ github.ref }}

  # I need to add a new step here. After all steps, I need to update the live folder with newly merged files.

  - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
    with:
      args: --follow-symlinks --cache-control max-age=600
    env:
      AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_BUCKET_NAME }}
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
      SOURCE_DIR: "f/js/live"
      DEST_DIR: "f/assets/js/test/"
```